# How to test a P2306 code - Ignition Coil error

Tags: sparkplugs, peugeot, ignition-coil, peugeot-208

I have a P2306 (Ignition Coil C Primary Control Circuit Low), so I swapped all ignition coils from their original place to another cylinder to verify the faulty ignition coil (I expect now to be in the first cylinder, A), but the same code persist after using the car for 2h.

Shall I erase the code and wait for the different error to appear, or will it eventually change by itself?

I believe it is only one faulty ignition coil, because my mechanic wants to change all 3 coils and 3 spark plugs for £400 while the price of all 6 pieces are just around £150, and I have all tools already.

Extra details:

- Peugeot 208 (2014) Petrol 1.0 engine
- 58,000 Miles

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Are you saying you never cleared the codes when changing the coils around?

Answer (score 0):

It's a good starting point to switch coils to see if the codes follow. But this code isn't cylinder specific. It may or may not be the coil. The primary circuit should be tested for adequate voltage and ground. Connectors need checked. Could also be a bad ecm.